# How to get value from Node in Selenium Webdriver and Print in Console?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have tried using Webelement to store value but
facing Error like :
[Below is the image of which I want to get value that is K1]

[image]

I am Not Getting value through Weblelement as It is displaying Error as

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //div[2]/label/strong/following-sibling::text()
is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.
```

I just want to store value in variable and print it, I have tried below code but no result :

WebElement Key = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/label/strong/following-sibling::text()"));
String vs =Key.getText();
System.out.println("key Name..!!!" + vs);

Suggest Me Opinions

Comment: plz edit your question....

Comment: I don't see the `<input>` tag in the `HTML` you shared, can you update the question including the tag? You may like to expand the first `div` too with `class=form-group`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this Xpath to obtain the WebElement:

> .//strong[text()='Key']/../..//label

After that with  element.getText() you should have the value : K1

Comment: I am not getting any value just throwing same error

Comment: Yes Finally it run successfully..Thank u j.barrio